# The best solution for creating logging system

Tags: sql-server-2005, logging, vb.net-2010, audit-trail

can someone tell me what the best solution is for creating logging system (Audit trail) !? 
I'm using vb.net with MSSQL 2005

Comment: can you elaborate the requirements of logging system

Comment: http://commondata.codeplex.com/ is the one you are looking for...

Comment: As a fact, I want to use this logging system for tracking users. what have they done, who inserted , who deleted , who updated into the database ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following thread will give you some tips about audio trail mechanism :

http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=615

Answer (score 2):

Try AutoAudit, which was developed by Paul Nielsen.

http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/